# how to remove background for color after clicking on the nav bar link

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I have written the code in the below link `Reza` https://codepen.io/vsandeep2516/pen/XWbzPVa. The issue is after a click on the navigation link white color patch is appearing.

@sanriot please refer the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following CSS:

```
.nav > li > a:focus, .nav > li > a:hover{
  background: transparent !important;
}
```

```js
var Deb = [];

$.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  Deb.push(document.location);

});
```

```css
/*add*/

.nav>li>a:focus,
.nav>li>a:hover {
  background: transparent!important;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font: 400 14px/24px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#header {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.head-top {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  z-index: 999;
}

#nav {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 16px 0 0 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 20px 0;
}

#nav .active {
  background: transparent;
}

#nav li a {
  font: 400 14px/14px 'Lato', sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20;
}

#nav li:hover>a {
  background: none;
}

#nav li ul li a:hover,
#nav li ul li:hover>a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<header id="header">
  <section class="head-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="left-side">
            <h1>sandeep</h1>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="right-side">
            <nav class="navbar ">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                        class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> </button>
              </div>
              <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#" data-tab='main'>Home</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#aboutus" data-tab="aboutus">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#gallery" data-tab="gallery">Gallery </a></li>
                  <li><a href="#career" data-tab="career">career</a></li>

                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</header>
```

Comment: I am unable to get that one kindly refer the screenshot below

Comment: @sandeep where is the screenshot/

Comment: @sandeep I updated answer source code. check it out. If the problem is resolved, click the check mark to the left of the answer :)

Comment: still I can see the issue

Comment: @sandeep i can't reproduce it on code snippet.

Comment: kindly select any one of the nav links and hover on some other location. then you can see a white patch can be enabled

Comment: @sandeep it can't reproduce... Try my answered code snippet  again after reloading with Ctrl + F5?

Comment: I have uploaded an image in the question section itself. kidly check it. still, if u feel the issue is not reproducible. I would like to share my screen

Comment: @sandeep i tried on jsfiddle, but not reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/rxynpkj3/

Answer (score 0):

Add this in the end

```
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
  background-color: red !important;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
  background-color: red !important;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
  background-color: red !important;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```